# Why can't I start isc-dhcp-server upon installation?

Tags: debian, dhcp, isc-dhcpd

I'm following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallMultiDistro)  tutorial to install Linux in a system that does not have CD reader nor USB boot capabilities. Eventually, I reached the point where I had to install `isc-dhcp-server` and I did, sort of.

`Apt` tells me that there's one partially installed package. I run `sudo apt-get install -f` and I get the following:

```
Job for isc-dhcp-server.service failed. See 'systemctl status isc-dhcp server.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript isc-dhcp-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package isc-dhcp-server (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
isc-dhcp-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I do `/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start` the prompt consists of the first two lines of the same message.

Output from `sudo systemctl status isc-dhcp-server`:

```
● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2014-12-12 13:19:25 CST; 2min 43s ago
  Process: 1677 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 12 13:19:23 semplice dhcpd[1684]: you want, please write a subnet declaration
Dec 12 13:19:23 semplice dhcpd[1684]: in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Dec 12 13:19:23 semplice dhcpd[1684]: to which interface eth0 is attached. **
Dec 12 13:19:23 semplice dhcpd[1684]: 
Dec 12 13:19:23 semplice dhcpd[1684]: 
Dec 12 13:19:25 semplice isc-dhcp-server[1677]: Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
Dec 12 13:19:25 semplice isc-dhcp-server[1677]: failed!
Dec 12 13:19:25 semplice systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 12 13:19:25 semplice systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
Dec 12 13:19:25 semplice systemd[1]: Unit isc-dhcp-server.service entered failed state.
```

Output from `sudo journalctl -xn`:

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2014-12-12 12:57:16 CST, end at Fri 2014-12-12 13:32:01 CST. --
Dec 12 13:31:58 semplice NetworkManager[505]: <info>   lease time 86400
Dec 12 13:31:58 semplice NetworkManager[505]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.254'
Dec 12 13:31:58 semplice NetworkManager[505]: <info>   domain name 'lan'
Dec 12 13:31:58 semplice dbus[518]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.ser
Dec 12 13:31:58 semplice dbus[518]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec 12 13:31:58 semplice nm-dispatcher[2194]: Dispatching action 'dhcp4-change' for wlan0
Dec 12 13:31:58 semplice dhclient[616]: bound to 192.168.1.65 -- renewal in 45 seconds.
Dec 12 13:31:58 semplice NetworkManager[505]: bound to 192.168.1.65 -- renewal in 45 seconds.
Dec 12 13:32:01 semplice sudo[2197]: alejandro : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/alejandro ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xn
Dec 12 13:32:01 semplice sudo[2197]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by alejandro(uid=0)
```

[This](http://pastebin.com/LeNfLYPi) is my `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.config` file wich is just a copy of the example in the tutorial mentioned above.

Output from `/var/log/syslog` read immediately after running `apt-get install -f`

```
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 192.168.1.254 port 67
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost NetworkManager[505]: DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 192.168.1.254 port 67
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost dhclient: DHCPACK from 192.168.1.254
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost NetworkManager[505]: DHCPACK from 192.168.1.254
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed renew -> renew
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info>   address 192.168.1.65
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info>   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info>   gateway 192.168.1.254
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info>   server identifier 192.168.1.254
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info>   lease time 86400
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.254'
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info>   domain name 'lan'
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost dbus[518]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost dbus[518]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec 12 16:42:40 localhost nm-dispatcher: Dispatching action 'dhcp4-change' for wlan0
Dec 12 16:42:41 localhost dhclient: bound to 192.168.1.65 -- renewal in 52 seconds.
Dec 12 16:42:41 localhost NetworkManager[505]: bound to 192.168.1.65 -- renewal in 52 seconds.
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 192.168.1.254 port 67
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost NetworkManager[505]: DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 192.168.1.254 port 67
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost dhclient: DHCPACK from 192.168.1.254
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost NetworkManager[505]: DHCPACK from 192.168.1.254
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed renew -> renew
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info>   address 192.168.1.65
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info>   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info>   gateway 192.168.1.254
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info>   server identifier 192.168.1.254
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info>   lease time 86400
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.254'
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost NetworkManager[505]: <info>   domain name 'lan'
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost dbus[518]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost dbus[518]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec 12 16:43:32 localhost nm-dispatcher: Dispatching action 'dhcp4-change' for wlan0
Dec 12 16:43:33 localhost dhclient: bound to 192.168.1.65 -- renewal in 54 seconds.
Dec 12 16:43:33 localhost NetworkManager[505]: bound to 192.168.1.65 -- renewal in 54 seconds.
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.1
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2014 Internet Systems Consortium.
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.1
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2014 Internet Systems Consortium.
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: Wrote 0 deleted host decls to leases file.
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: Wrote 0 new dynamic host decls to leases file.
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: 
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: No subnet declaration for eth0 (no IPv4 addresses).
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd:    to which interface eth0 is attached. **
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: 
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: 
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: 
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: 
Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: exiting.
Dec 12 16:43:42 localhost isc-dhcp-server[5729]: Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
Dec 12 16:43:42 localhost isc-dhcp-server[5729]: failed!
Dec 12 16:43:42 localhost systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 12 16:43:42 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
Dec 12 16:43:42 localhost systemd[1]: Unit isc-dhcp-server.service entered failed state.
```

Should I hide my ip address?

Comment: Did you do what to those two lines say, i.e. run systemclt and look at the journal? Please post the output from `journalctl -xn` generated (might have to sudo it) while you try to rerun `apt-get install -f`

Comment: So it's `dhcpd` that isn't starting, and we're getting only the end of its messages here. Looks like it's complaining about `dhcpd.conf` missing some required information. You need to go a bit further back in the system logs, to see the whole series of messages from `dhcpd`. On a traditional system the logs should be in `/var/log/syslog`, I don't know if systemd messes that up.

Answer (score 5):

It seems your network configuration isn't matching your subnet declaration in dhcp.conf. Make sure that you have an IP address from the 10.10.1.0/24 subnet configured. You can check this using:

```
ip a
```

If you don't see such an IP address try adding it to e. g. eth0:

```
ip a a 10.10.1.200/24 dev eth0
```

After that try again fixing the package:

```
apt-get install -f
```

If I'm correct, it should install the package and start the DHCP daemon and you might want to persist this IP address in /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: Note: `ip a a` stands for `ip address add`

Comment: had this error on my rasp pi and couldnt start service, turned out no IP address in ip a command output. after adding ip address everything worked

Comment: @Manny265 Your comment doesn't make sense; the reason you run DHCP is that it should assign an IP address for you automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here:

> ```
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: No subnet declaration for eth0 (no IPv4 addresses).
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd:    to which interface eth0 is attached. **
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: 
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: 
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: 
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: 
> Dec 12 16:43:40 localhost dhcpd: exiting.
> ```

You should be able to reproduce the error message by running `dhcpd -t -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`.

---

I'm guessing that you want to share a wireless Internet connection to other hosts on Ethernet, as in the topology diagram below.

```
                            ↑
                            │ Uplink
                            │
               ┌────────────┴────────────┐
               │          wlan0          │
               │     192.168.1.65/24     │
               │                         │
               │        semplice         │
               │                         │
               │       10.10.1.1/24      │
               │          eth0           │
               └────────────┬────────────┘
                            │
     ┌──────────────┬───────┴────────┬──────────────┐
     │              │                │              │
   Host 1         Host 2           Host 3         Host 4
 10.10.1.21     10.10.1.22       10.10.1.23     10.10.1.24
```

I'm assuming that your server's address for `eth0` is 10.10.1.1.  Verify that by running `ip addr show dev eth0`.

**Then you must configure** `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` to hand out addresses on the `eth0` interface.  Out of the box, `dhcpd` is configured not to respond to anything, because an inadvertently running rogue DHCP server would wreak havoc on a network by handing out addresses to any host that asks for one.

In `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`, you'll need a stanza like the following:

```
subnet 10.10.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option subnet-mask        255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address  10.10.1.255;
    option routers            10.10.1.1;
    pool {
        range 10.10.1.21 10.10.1.254;
    }
}
```

… in addition to declarations such as `authoritative`, `domain-name`, `domain-name-servers`, and `default-lease-time`.  (Adjust as necessary.  Only you know what settings you want for your network.)

Also, for Debian, you'll need to edit `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` to set

```
INTERFACES="eth0"
```

so that the server will listen on the Ethernet port.  (You do not want to listen on `wlan0`; your wireless access point would be responsible for handing out addresses to wireless clients.)

Comment: His problem is that systemd is ignoring the lsb init info of the old init script, which clearly states "# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network $syslog". Instead of waiting for the network units it starts it will parallelize dhcpd to run even before that.

Comment: A valid `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` configuration file should be used to solve this problem. The `isc-dhcp-server` service  will fail using a wrong `dhcpd.conf` configuration.